# set_select for select tag in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to set value for select tag ,as when i tried for text field

```
<input type="input" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name') ?>"/>
```

its working but when i tried for select tag

```
<SELECT class="form-control" name="user" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <?php
        foreach ($result as $row):
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' >" . $row['employee_name'];
    ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</SELECT>
```

its not working ,when validation run falls its again showing --Select-- option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this--> use set_select()

```
<select id="user" name="user" style="width: 230px; height: 40px;" >
<option value="" selected>--Select--</option>
<?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ; ?>" <?php echo set_select('user', $row['id'], False); ?> ><?php echo $row['employee_name'] ; ?> </option> 
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Codeigniter Dropdown list you should use `set_select()` instead of `set_value()` function. You can use like

```
<select name="myselect">
<option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', TRUE); ?> >One</option>
<option value="two" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'two'); ?> >Two</option>
<option value="three" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'three'); ?> >Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

best way is to use form_dropdown method to use these as you are already looping and creating options create option array in controller and pass it to view like

```
$options = array('--Select--');

foreach ($result as $row){
     $options[$row['id']] = $row['employee_name'];
}

echo form_dropdown('user',$options,set_select('user','default_value'));
```

if not any select value from dropdown then default value will be used

Comment: i tried this but still its not not showing selected value

Comment: its should run with validation can you share validation rules how you are using validation and also form action too

Comment: Does not work, you need `set_value` instead of `set_select` if you want to use this inside the `form_dropdown` function.

Answer (score -1):

this might help you.

```
<SELECT class="form-control" name="user" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <?php
        foreach ($result as $row):
        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."' set_select('user', $row['id']);.">". $row['employee_name'];
    ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</SELECT>
```