# how to retain values in dropdown using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
<select id="store_owner"  class="form-control" name="store_owner">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <?php foreach ($admin_email as $adminData):?>

        <option value="<?php echo $adminData['service_provider_email_id']?>"><?php echo $adminData['service_provider_email_id']?></option>

    <?php endforeach;?>   
</select>
<?php if (form_error('store_owner')) { ?><span style="color: #E68F8F;"><?php echo form_error('store_owner'); ?></span> <?php } ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

the value should retain if the form is partially validated.How to retain the values of select field. Please check my code.

Comment: Please explain more in your question.

Comment: once i click on submit button ,partially filled data should be retained..i am able to do it for text boxes..but i am not able to retain the value selected in drop down

Comment: You're not setting the `selected` old value in your loop that builds drop down list. You can use the CI form helper functions `form_dropdown()` or `set_select()`. [See here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28273500/3585500).

Comment: ok..i tried and i got it.Thank you .