# how dynamic dropdown set select use

Tags: php, codeigniter

am doing like this. this is my dynamic dropdown which is populating from database result. when i submit the form, validation apply, if validation error occur on empty field, form stops to submit. BUT **all dropdown also removes its values, so i again fill all form instead of empty fields**

my previous code is: before apply set select

```
<select name="position_filled_against_id" id="position_filled_against_id">
 <option value="">Select</option>
<?php
foreach($position_filled_against as $position_filled)
{
 $selected = "";
 echo '<option value="'.$position_filled->position_filled_against_id.'" >'.$position_filled->code.'-'.$position_filled->name.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

after apply set select: but syntax error

```
<select name="position_filled_against_id" id="position_filled_against_id"><option value="">Select</option>
<?php
  foreach($position_filled_against as $position_filled)
  {
     $selected = "";
     echo '<option value="'.set_select("position_filled_against_id",$position_filled->position_filled_against_id,TRUE).'" >'.$position_filled->code.'-'.$position_filled->name.'</option>';
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273127/set-select-for-select-tag-in-codeigniter

Comment: it gives only syntax error. i want to set the value of dropdown after validation apply

Comment: but no error shown

Comment: your kind advice need, would u like to do same thing apply on my code , bcoz am having syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i remove the syntax error

```
<select name="position_filled_against_id" id="position_filled_against_id">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php

    foreach($position_filled_against as $position_filled)
    {
     $selected = "";
     echo '<option value="'.$position_filled->position_filled_against_id.'" '.set_select("position_filled_against_id","$position_filled->position_filled_against_id", TRUE).' >'.$position_filled->code.'-'.$position_filled->name.'</option>';
     }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code it will help you

```
<select name="position_filled_against_id" id="position_filled_against_id">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php
foreach($position_filled_against as $position_filled)
{
 $selected = "";
 if($_REQUEST['position_filled_against_id']==$position_filled->position_filled_against_id)
 {
   $selected = 'selected="selected"';
 }
 echo '<option value="'.$position_filled->position_filled_against_id.'" '.$selected.' >'.$position_filled->code.'-'.$position_filled->name.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```