# Set select the value of a dropdown menu in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, dropdown, selected

I know how to set the inserted value if it is an input control.

Example :

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['regData']['fullname']) ? set_value('fullname', $_SESSION['regData']['fullname']) : set_value('fullname'); ?>">
```

This code will still display your inserted value after the submit button. But how should I apply it with the `dropdown` control?

I tried to do like this but it's not working :

```
<select name="gender" class="form-control">
    <?php

    if(!empty($genders)){
        foreach ($genders as $row) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'"';

            if($row['id'] == $_SESSION['regData']['gender']){
                echo set_select('gender', $_SESSION['regData']['gender']);
            } else {
                echo set_select('gender', $row['id']);
            }

            echo '>'.$row['gender_title'].'</option>';
        }
    }

    ?>
</select>
```

What is the correct way to apply it? Thank you.

Comment: I've checked it. That's for remaining the value based on the user input. But my case is I have those data stored in a session and I want to do a matching value. If the value is same only do the `selected`. I can do that by just echo the `selected` but when submitting data and the form throwing error, the dropdown displaying back the session data instead of the data that been selected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274807/1939258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a trick to do this. From the controller I have set a variable to the gender if the `form_validation->run()` is failed.

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
    // Other statement goes here
} else {
    $this->data['gender'] = TRUE;
}
```

At my view side I do it like this :

```
<select name="gender" class="form-control">
    <?php
    if(!empty($genders)){
        foreach ($genders as $row) {

            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'"';

            if(isset($gender)){
                echo set_select('gender', $row['id']);
            } else {
                if(isset($_SESSION['regData']['gender']) && $_SESSION['regData']['gender'] == $row['id']){
                    echo 'selected';
                }
            }

            echo '>'.$row['gender_title'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

So when the form is submitted and throwing an error, instead of reading the value of the session, it will read the value based on the user select.

Answer (score 0):

[`set_select`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1.7/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L727) checks the input value in the `$_POST` array.

In order to make use of the session store, you can write the following helper in `application/helpers` directory.

**form_extras.php**

```
if ( ! function_exists('set_select_session'))
{
   function set_select_session($field, $sessionKeyPath, $value = '', $default = FALSE)
   {
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $sessionPart = $CI->session->userdata();
      foreach($sessionKeyPath as $key) {
         $sessionPart = $sessionPart[$key];
      }

      if ($sessionPart[$field] == $value) {
        return 'selected';
      }
      return set_select($field, $value, $default);
   }
}
```

Load it

```
$this->load->helper('form_extras');
```

Then use it in your view.

```
<select name="gender" class="form-control">
    <?php
    if(!empty($genders)){
        foreach ($genders as $row) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'"';

            echo set_select_session('gender', ['regData'], $row['id']);

            echo '>'.$row['gender_title'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Otherwise, doing it directly in the view is just fine.

```
if(!empty($genders)){
    foreach ($genders as $row) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'"';

        if($row['id'] == $_SESSION['regData']['gender']){
            echo 'selected';
        } else {
            echo set_select('gender', $row['id']);
        }

        echo '>'.$row['gender_title'].'</option>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Okay I tried to apply the helper in my system but then it throws me error `Using $this when not in object context` on the line `$sessionPart = $this->session->userdata();`